# how to read a db2 table into python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python to connect to DB2 Database

I have installed ibm_db and ibm_dbi packages and imported in to the code

import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi

1)created a connection string as conn_str

---

conn_str='database=pydev;hostname=host.test.com;port=portno;protocol=tcpip;uid=db2inst1;pwd=secret'

> > > ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str,'','')
> > >
> > > ### conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(ibm_db_conn)

2)Now i need to read a DB2 table which is in under schemas called as "BRUD" into python pandas

could any one please help me in getting the connection for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about sql syntax, but resolution looks like:

```py
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM BRUD.table_name', conn)
```